# Count number of functions

Tags: combinatorics

Given $A=\bigl\{f\mid f:\{1,2,3\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4\}\bigr\},\; f$ is a function.

How many elements of $A$ satisfy $f(3)>f(2)$?

I know that the total amount of functions is $4^3$, I am not sure how to proceed with the sets needed. Can you help me define the sets I need to work with?

Comment: Note that there's a preview under the textbox where you enter the question, and an edit button under the question once you've submitted it, so you can still fix the syntax error that's messing up the first line. (Note also that MathJax uses braces for grouping, so even when you've balanced them correctly, you'll need to escape them with backslashes (`\{...\}`) to make them visible.)

Comment: Thank you and sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Each two-element subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ can be uniquely assigned to the values of $f(2),f(3)$ such that $f(2)<f(3)$ and vice versa.  For example $\{2,4\}$ would correspond with $f(2)=2$ and $f(3)=4$, while $\{4,1\}$ would correspond with $f(2)=1$ and $f(3)=4$.  (*Remember $\{4,1\}=\{1,4\}$, that order within a /set/ is irrelevant*)

How many ways are there to choose a two-element subset of a four-element set?  This is then the number of ways of selecting the values for $f(2)$ and $f(3)$.  Couple this as well with the number of ways of selecting the value of $f(1)$ and apply the rule of product to arrive at a final answer.

> Your answer in the (*now deleted*) comments of the other answer: "*I think I got it. Is it possible to add 4(3)+4(2)+4(1)? First choosing the element for f(2) and counting the numbers that make f(3)>f(2)?*"  This is correct and $4(3)+4(2)+4(1)$ is indeed the correct answer... However... it feels a bit too much like brute force and does not as easily generalize as it otherwise could.  What if we were asking for $f(3)<f(4)<f(5)<\dots<f(100)$ and our codomain were $\{1,2,3,4,\dots,1000\}$.  Your method would not have been feasible, but the method I am trying to lead you to above is still straightforward and easy to calculate.